# Making loop in object array, but not printing?

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to coding, and trying to make simple script to print this json into html table.

Whats wrong with it ?

And the next step would be create input fields to add new data.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

let bigHero = {characters:[
            {name:'Hiro', voice:'Ryan Potter'},
            {name:'Baymax', voice:'Scott Adsit'},
            {name:'Go Go Tamago', voice:'Jamie Chung'},
            {name:'Fred', voice:'T.J. Miller'}
        ]};

let chars = bigHero['characters'];  
  for(let i=0, len=chars.length; i<len; i++){
  text += "<tr>";
     for(let prop in chars[i]){
        text += "<td>" + chars[i][name] + "</td>";
        text += "<td>" + chars[i][voice] + "</td>";
}
  text += "</tr>";
  return text;
}

</script>
```

Comment: At the end, change `text = "</tr>"` to `text += "</tr>"` (you are now overwriting the value of text instead of appending). Also, you have `<td>` followed by `</li>` which does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks, made changes, but still not printing

Comment: @LigitasSpondzevicius Check my answer if you are open to an alternative approach that is shorter and cleaner and less prone to errors. But if you prefer the `for loop` approach, I have included  solution using the `for loop` too in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You keep **overwriting** the value of the `text` variable in each iteration.

```
text = "</tr>";
```

If you do this, you should make sure you process the variable contents at the end of each loop iteration, before it is overwritten again and all previous work is undone.

Below is an **example**, assuming you want to show the contents of the `bigHero` variable in the "demo" tag.
We clear the content before the loop and add the contents of the `text` variable to the DOM element at the end of each loop iteration.

Alternatively, you could also replace the contents of the DOM element with the variable content after the whole loop.

```js
let bigHero = {
    characters: [{
            name: 'Hiro',
            voice: 'Ryan Potter'
        },
        {
            name: 'Baymax',
            voice: 'Scott Adsit'
        },
        {
            name: 'Go Go Tamago',
            voice: 'Jamie Chung'
        },
        {
            name: 'Fred',
            voice: 'T.J. Miller'
        }
    ]
};

let chars = bigHero.characters,
    demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
    text = "";

// add content to DOM at the end of each iteration, before text variable is 'reset'
demo.innerHTML = "";
for (let i = 0, len = chars.length; i < len; i++) {
    text = "<tr>";
    text += "<td>" + chars[i].name + " </li>";
    text += "<td>" + chars[i].voice + " </li></tr>";
    demo.innerHTML += text;
}

// alternative: keep adding to text variable and add content to DOM element after whole loop completed
text = "";
for (let i = 0, len = chars.length; i < len; i++) {
    text += "<tr>";
    text += "<td>" + chars[i].name + " </li>";
    text += "<td>" + chars[i].voice + " </li></tr>";
}
demoTwo.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<table id="demo"></p>
</br>
<table id="demoTwo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same desired result with barely 2-3 lines of code using a combination of the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method along with [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) instead like this:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
let bigHero = {characters:[{name:'Hiro', voice:'Ryan Potter'},{name:'Baymax', voice:'Scott Adsit'},{name:'Go Go Tamago', voice:'Jamie Chung'},{name:'Fred', voice:'T.J. Miller'}]};         
let chars = bigHero.characters;

// Using map() method
chars.map(char => {
 x.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${char.name}</td><td>${char.voice}</td></tr>`
});
```

```html
<table id="demo"></table>
```

---

But if you prefer the **for loop** approach:

Just declare an empty string variable for the result say, `res` and whenever the `for loop` finishes a cycle, it pushes it's content to the res variable and resets itself back to an empty variable.

Then once the for loop has completed, just simply push the `res` variable string to your `#demo` table using `innerHTML()` as follows:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var res = "";

let bigHero = {characters:[
            {name:'Hiro', voice:'Ryan Potter'},
            {name:'Baymax', voice:'Scott Adsit'},
            {name:'Go Go Tamago', voice:'Jamie Chung'},
            {name:'Fred', voice:'T.J. Miller'}
        ]};

let chars = bigHero.characters;
  for(let i=0; i<chars.length; i++){
   text = "<tr>";
    text += "<td>" + chars[i].name + "</td>";
    text += "<td>" + chars[i].voice + "</td>";
   text += "</tr>";
    
    res += text;
 }
  x.innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<table id="demo"></table>
```